# WorkflowControlClient - Access Is Denied

Tags: c#, wcf, workflow

My client's system been using Workflow for handling task and its been working well until last few days. Now it constantly shows "Access is Denied" error message but I have no idea which part of access is denied. Things that I can think of were :

1. Database connection
2. Server access of database
3. Access to the WCF service.

Below shown is the error message:

> Access is denied. 
>   Server stack trace:
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRunTime
>   operation, ProxyRpc&rpc)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, Imessage retMsg)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Acivities.IworkflowInstanceManagement.Unsuspend(Guid
>   ID)

Added on 20th Aug. Found new error message in Event Log and not sure if this helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<s:Header>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">
http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault
</a:Action>
<a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:abc123-123-123-123-abc123</a:RelatesTo>
</s:Header><s:Body><s:Fault>
<s:Code>
<s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
<s:Subcode>
<s:Value xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:FailedAuthentication</s:Value>
</s:Subcode></s:Code>
<s:Reason>
<s:Text xml:lang="en-US">Access is denied.
</s:Text>
</s:Reason>
</s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Can someone point me a direction on how can I solve this issue. Thanks

Tried :

1. Use the account to login db server
2. Restart WCF host server

Added on 22 AUG 2019:

Checked the workflow solution and found that the exception occurs exactly when its attempting to run WorkflowControlClient.Unsuspense(GUID) / WorkflowControlClient.Terminate(GUID). Unable to check further as its a function from ServiceModel

Comment: You may have a cookie/certificate that expired or got corrupted.  Have client using IE delete cookies and try again.  Also check certificates for data of expiration.  If you don't find anything then have client use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to capture http messages.  The exception indicates a connection didn't complete and eventually timed out.There are lots of reason for the connection did not complete.The error is indicating that a connection to the proxy server failed, but that still may be due to a route to the proxy not completing and may have nothing to do with the certificate.

Comment: How long has the application been running on clients system?  Certificates usually are for a year (or multiple years).  You may have a issue getting a connection to a DNS server which gets updated monthly.  So sometimes knowing how long something worked is an indication of why it started to fail.

Comment: @jdweng Will data of expiration cause this issue? Been having the certificate error all the time (in test environment) and its been working fine. May I know how do I check the route to proxy not completing issue you mentioned?

Comment: Is DCHP enabled?  DCHP automatically assigns an IP address to a computer. The IP address will change periodically (usually monthly).  So when DCHP is enabled you must use the Computer Name (not IP address).  To check route to a server use cmd.exe >Ping IP (or computer name).  This will only tell you if there is a route and will not indicate if the server is listening on the port.  To tell if the server is listening use cmd.exe >Netstat -a which will give a list of status of all UDP and TCP connections.  If the service is not running then the port number will not be shown.

Comment: @jdweng added new content with error message I found from event log

Comment: Have you tried restarting your WCF server host? It seems that there is something wrong with the server health.

Comment: @AbrahamQian Can you further explain what do you mean by something wrong with the server health?

Comment: It looks like your SOAP is not properly signed (oasis wssecurity from exception).  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security

Comment: which is security mode in the WCF binding, what is the client credential type? Such as the client needs to provide a windows credential when calling the service,  and your server has changed the account password recently. this may cause the access failure. Besides, Does the WCF server has changed or updated?

Comment: @jdweng if in the workflow system(called by wcf), I'm able to insert a db record with unique exception message. This should means its not SOAP issue right? I have updated the question with info of exact method that throws the exception

Comment: @AbrahamQian I doubt its WCF issue as I'm able to add unique exception message and save it into DB within workflow system that is triggered by WCF. The _your server has changed the account password recently_ is a question or you noticed something I didnt?

Comment: Check the Event logs to see if there is useful info.   You can then use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Check the last request to service and the last response.  The good responses should have a status of 200 OK.  You are probably not getting the 200.  Then look at last request and see what the message contains.